# New sails app preinstalls many node modules

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm in the process of learning Sails and for some reason when I create a new sails app using "sails new foobar" the new app installs 129 node modules into the foobar/node_modules directory.

In my previous working experience with node the node_modules folder usually isn't populated until either "npm install" is run after updating the package.json or if modules are specifically installed.

Looking over other tutorials the node_modules folder isn't created upon creating a new app, as expected. Could this be a problem with my npm installation?

My package.json dependencies section looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "~0.11.3",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Even if sails new ran npm install for me automatically, the package.json file doesn't have that many node modules in it. I updated the question to include the dependencies listed in the package.json file.

Comment: Definitely an error in your installation. I had a similar error that involved circular dependencies. Uninstall and reinstall sails to fix it.

Comment: I tried doing so, and unfortunately it didn't work. I'm going to try reinstalling npm and then node if that doesn't work.

Comment: usually on running `sails new MyAwesomProject`, sails automatically creates a folder `node_modules` in the directory. The contents are supposed to be a link to globally installed modules. Are you sure its not just the links?

Comment: Yes, the node modules are in the directory and don't link elsewhere. For what it's worth, when creating a new sails application on my Macbook everything works as expected. I'm just going to create the app on my Mac, push it to GitHub, and pull from the Linux machine when I need to dev on it.